# android- how to go to last activity on backbutton

Tags: android

this is a problem that is really a big one . 
I go to activity a ,I can go to several activities like activity b ,c and d . 
if I go to activity b and I press back button , I go to activity a , that right , but when I press back button again , it goes to activity b instead of leaving activity a, I press back button again and I go to activity a and If if i press it again , then I get out of activity a . 
I mean , it repeat the whole way I go and then leave it .

it shouldn't be like this ,I need to leave activity a if I press back button not repeating activities .

I can't use intent for this because of another problem that I get ,I tried finish() onBackPressed , didn't work.

How can I do so ?

thanks you

Comment: post whole `ACtivity A's` code

Comment: When you start an activity using an Intent, then if you haven't redefined anything (for example the activity creation to singleTop), then you will go back to the previously started activity.

Comment: you should post the activity responsible for the creation of any other activity, and the android manifest xml

Comment: @Zhuinden  How can I do so ? what should I say in manifest ?

Comment: Edit your post and include this informatino